# How to decrypt AES CBC?

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I used [this link](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption) to test decrypting AES CBC.

Here my parameters:

[image]

This work. Then I implement with C#. My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace HHT.Module.eWallet.Helper
{
    public class AESHelper
    {
        private AesCryptoServiceProvider _aes;
        private ICryptoTransform _crypto;

        public AESHelper(string key, string IV)
        {
            _aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            _aes.BlockSize = 128;
            _aes.KeySize = 256;
            _aes.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IV)) {
                _aes.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
            }
        
            _aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            _aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        }

        public string encrypt(string message)
        {
            _crypto = _aes.CreateEncryptor(_aes.Key, _aes.IV);
            byte[] encrypted = _crypto.TransformFinalBlock(
                ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message), 0, ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message).Length);
            _crypto.Dispose();
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
        }

        public string decrypt(string message)
        {
            _crypto = _aes.CreateDecryptor(_aes.Key, _aes.IV);
            byte[] decrypted = _crypto.TransformFinalBlock(
                System.Convert.FromBase64String(message), 0, System.Convert.FromBase64String(message).Length);
            _crypto.Dispose();
            return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(decrypted);
        }
    }
}
```

The function `decrypt` not work, it return wrong string. I think some parameters is not same as the picture.

Base64-encoded encrypted data:

```
5qG6aB4UZ6bnbbPgFhnC+qp/FJ7ZuZ+fg1cYm+OUM1uP/6PyWfLg0w5bJstmBf2W
```

Key:

```
745d88b1e8f75d320c2bd9198c08485d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the IV to all zeroes because otherwise it starts with a random value:

```cs
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IV))
{
    _aes.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
}
else
{
    _aes.IV = new byte[_aes.BlockSize / 8];
}
```

With this fix in place, it gets the  [same result](https://rextester.com/CLLJG47564) as the online site you used.

Also note that your question says ECB but your code and screenshot use CBC (and it's AES, not ACS).